# Add rows to generate a summary using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Given the following ordered dataset (1 minute intervals), how would I use Microsoft SQL Server to create a new record set that adds up all the individual codes for a given item and presents the summary as shown below? I am thinking that I should be able to use some kind of aggregate function over a partition but I don't know where to start.

Note that the `DateTime` is `datetime` and the remaining columns are of type `varchar`. I am using SQL Server 2012 Express.

Input data:

```
 DateTime              Item      Code    Description
 2016-12-02 16:34:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:35:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:36:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:37:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:38:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:39:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:40:00   0         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:41:00   0         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:42:00   0         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:43:00   0         4       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:44:00   0         4       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:45:00   0         4       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:46:00   0         4       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:47:00   0         4       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:48:00   1         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:49:00   1         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:50:00   1         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:51:00   1         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:52:00   1         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:53:00   1         3       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:54:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:55:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:56:00   0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:57:00   0         8       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:58:00   0         8       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:59:00   0         8       Some Description
 2016-12-02 17:00:00   0         6       Some Description
 2016-12-02 17:01:00   0         6       Some Description
```

Expected output data (start date should be the datetime of the first occurrence of the code and end date should be the last occurrence of the code):

```
 Start DT             End DT               Item      Code    Description
 2016-12-02 16:34:00  2016-12-02 16:39:00  0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:40:00  2016-12-02 16:42:00  0         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:43:00  2016-12-02 16:47:00  0         4       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:48:00  2016-12-02 16:49:00  1         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:50:00  2016-12-02 16:52:00  1         2       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:53:00  2016-12-02 16:53:00  1         3       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:54:00  2016-12-02 16:56:00  0         1       Some Description
 2016-12-02 16:57:00  2016-12-02 16:59:00  0         8       Some Description
 2016-12-02 17:00:00  2016-12-02 17:01:00  0         6       Some Description
```

Comment: It would be great if you could supply some real dates in the sample data.

Comment: Appologies Felix, I was should have included to assist with testing etc. I have included the datetime now.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to group islands of contiguous dates. [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/) is an article written by Jeff Moden that provides a solution to this problem:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = DATEADD(MINUTE, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item, Code ORDER BY DateTime), Datetime)
    FROM Data
)
SELECT
    StartDate   = MIN(DateTime),
    EndDate     = MAX(DateTime),
    Item,
    Code,
    Description = MAX(Description)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY 
    Item, Code, rn
ORDER BY
    StartDate, EndDate;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/590584)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the input Felix, I will check it out!